# in Symfony 2 : How to do a select of entity names in a form when entities are linked by id

Tags: forms, symfony, entity

I've two entities, let's call them entityA and entityB, entityA has a not nullable attribute entityBID. In my form for entityA creation I'd like to add a select with some entityB names ( not id ) that I would select in a function ( which would be in Repository/entityBRepository if possible ).

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you're asking, but i guess you are making a **choice** (or **entity**) field type of entityB class.
Those kind of field use the **__toString()** function of entity class (or getId() by default).

So just add in your entityB class

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getName();
}
```

Comment: Ok gg , that was brillant, simple and effective :)

Comment: but how can i do a selection ? ( with a query )